# Анализ теста производительности | JS

Tags: javascript, производительность

Тестируя производительность заметил Animation в целых 3с. Но не могу понять, откуда она вызывается. Можете подсказать, как узнать происхождение этого события? Summary и прочее не выдает вообще никакой информации. Тест производил в Opera GX, но могу и в другом браузере, если надо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]